# Minimise and maximise MetroWindow when ShowMessageAsync is being displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am using Mah Apps Metro in a WPF application and showing messages to users with their async dialog messages.

At a particular point in the application I am erasing a removable device which could take some time, in the mean time showing the user the `ShowProgressAsync` dialog until it completes.

```
var controller = await this.ShowProgressAsync("Please wait", "Preforming secure erase, this could take some time...", false, mds);
```

During the time the dialog is on the screen, it is not possible to interact with the window's minimise and maximise buttons and it's also not possible to move the window.

Is there a way I am able to show the dialog to the user and allow them to minimise/maximise/move the window or will I be forever stuck with the application in the location the dialog was displayed until it is closed?

(side note: the grip in the bottom right corner of the window will allow me to manually resize the window, just not the buttons on the title bar)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MappApp dialog is modal, so you cannot touch anything in the background because this is its purpose. As far as I know (for now) you cannot made modifications on this scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that